# How can I determine the length, in seconds, of a Vorbis stream?

Tags: c, vorbis

How can I determine the length, in seconds, of the Ogg Vorbis stream with libvorbis and/or libvorbisfile?

As far as I can tell, there's nothing in the [vorbis_info](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/libvorbis/vorbis_info.html) structure that tells me the length of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the lower level API, you can do this with [`ov_time_total`](http://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/ov_time_total.html).